# How to use SSL Certificate in xmpp IOS?

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, chat, openfire, xmppframework

Hi I am working with the XMPP Framework every thing is working fine. Now because of security reasons i need to work with ssl Certificate.But I don't know how to implement in my application even i don't know basic thing for SSL Certificate so can any body please help me how to create SSL. and how to implement in xmpp in ios and I am working with openfire server.

Comment: refer this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/certs#generate_a_certificate_signing_request_file

Comment: @darjiJigar Thanks for the Replay But that is for push Notifications right?that one is also work for xmpp Framework sorry if my question is wrong

Answer (score 0):

> Hey, I successfully implemented SSL in XMPP, Follow these steps below:

step- 1:

```
-(BOOL) connect {

    [self setupStream];

    [xmppStream setHostName:xxx];
    [xmppStream setHostPort:zzz];
    [xmppStream setMyJID:yyy];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![xmppStream oldSchoolSecureConnectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error]) {

    nslog(@"Error %@",error)

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;

}
```

step- 2:

```
- (void)setupStream {

    customCertEvaluation = NO;
    allowSelfSignedCertificates = NO;
    allowSSLHostNameMismatch = NO;


    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    xmppStream.startTLSPolicy = XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicyPreferred;
    // or
    // xmppStream.startTLSPolicy = XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicyRequired;

}
```

step- 3 : set flags according to your server needs

```
 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willSecureWithSettings:(NSMutableDictionary *)settings
    {
        NSString *expectedCertName = [xmppStream.myJID domain];

        if (customCertEvaluation){
            [settings setObject:@(YES) forKey:GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust];
        }
        //    if (allowSelfSignedCertificates){
        //        [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot];
        //    }
        if (allowSSLHostNameMismatch){
            [settings setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
        }
        else{
            if (expectedCertName)
                [settings setObject:expectedCertName forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
        }
    }
```